# Evernote, most efficeint way to find notes with tasks

Tags: evernote

I'm building a simple app to list all my todos form Evernote and other apps. To find them form Evernote I am searching for all notes then filter those that contains `<en-todo`.

But there may be a better way than retreiving all content and filtering ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search on "todo:true" to find notes with at least one checkbox checked,  or
"todo:false" to find notes with at least one checkbox unchecked.

See the "Advanced Content Matching" section of [this page from Evernote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/search_grammar.php).